# Asp.net MVC5 async action result executed, but response not sent till web server shutdown

Tags: async-await, iis-express, asp.net-mvc-5, c#-5.0

I have an async action, which is supposed to return a JSON message to the browser after awaiting some task. Though the ActionResult is built and executed successfully(I'm using my own JsonResult, so I confirmed this by stepping into the source), the browser still gets no response(confirmed by Fiddler).

Meanwhile, it works if I'm awaiting for `Task.Delay()`, and returning a dummy message.

Strangely, if I rebuild my projects with VS2013 while the IIS Express running my website, all the sudden the browser receives the message that was supposed to be sent several  minutes ago! I think it's shutting down the web server makes this happen, however I can't figure out how exactly this is happening.

I've been debugging for a day, disabled everything that I thought could have been related, with no luck. So any help about what could be the cause to this strange behavior is welcome. Thanks, here is the code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> Update(string token)
    {
        try
        {
            //This works
            //await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            //return Json(new { error = "testing." });

            //This won't work
            var feedback = await ServerConnectionKeeper.UpdateStation(token);

            return feedback.Success
                ? Json(new { redirect = Url.Action("Index", "Home") })
                : Json(new { error = feedback.Error });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { error = ex.Message });
        }
    }
```

Comment: If `Task.Delay` works and `SeverConnectionKeeper.UpdateStation` doesn't, then there is probably a problem somewhere in `UpdateStation`. Ensure that you have set `targetFramework` to `4.5` in your `web.config` and that you have *not* set `AllowAsyncDuringSyncStages`.

Comment: @StephenCleary I've checked the `targetFramework`, it is `4.5`. I have stepped into `SeverConnectionKeeper.UpdateStation`, and didn't found anything unusual. And the final `JsonResult` has always been executed.

Comment: Do you have `AllowAsyncDuringSyncStages` set?

Comment: `HttpContext.Current.AllowAsyncDuringSyncStages` is `false`. I don't think I have touched this property in my codes.

Comment: Tried setting `HttpContext.AllowAsyncDuringSyncStages` to `true`, the result is still the same.

Comment: Well, back to my original comment: it works with `Task.Delay`. It does not work with `UpdateStation`. To me it seems that `UpdateStation` contains the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I agree, but what problem could it be, where should I look into? There is no unhandled exceptions, and the fact I used `ConfigureAwait(false)` inside that method should not affected the caller.

Comment: First, reduce the code until you have a "minimal repro" - that is, the smallest amount of code that causes the problem. Then take a good look at the code; if you can't find it, post that code.

Comment: Thanks for your advise, I'm doing this the last two hours. And now I found why: I called a `async void XXX()` method in `UpdateStation()`, after changing the signature to `async Task XXX()` and called it with `ConfigureAwait(false)` (still not awaiting it), my code works. Never knew this would cost my day, still wondering why.

Comment: I'll clean up the mess I made during debugging, and write down all the problems and solutions as an answer tomorrow, hoping it can help others. Or myself next time, who knows. Thanks again, @StephenCleary.

Comment: `async void` should throw an `InvalidOperationException` in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that I called an `async void` method, which made some strange unknown(by me) things happen. Here is the some conceptual code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> Data()
    {
        await SomeTask();
        return Json(new { message = "Testing" });
    }

    private async Task SomeTask()
    {
        FireAndForget();
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    private async void FireAndForget()
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100)).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

With above code, I thought the response would come 1 second after requesting. But it does not, not even 100 seconds after. In some cases I get a `InvalidOperationException`, in other cases I get nothing.

If I change the `async void` to `async Task`, either `ConfigureAwait(false)` or not, every thing works:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> Data()
    {
        await SomeTask();
        return Json(new { message = "Testing 4" });
    }

    private async Task SomeTask()
    {
        FireAndForget();
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    private async Task FireAndForget()
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100)).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

The reason responses are sent when web server shutting down in my production code, is because my `FireAndForget()` method there is an `async` loop reading network messages, and never returns untill the connection closed, and shutting down the web server closes the connection. It's still strange to me that I didn't get `InvalidOperationException` there though.